# I need to block torrent downloads

Tags: firewall, bittorrent, traffic-shaping

My cousin complains that his housemate uses torrent and thus it causes slow connection to my cousin.

He owns the ADSL modem and I saw some good futures such as blocking websites or protocols. Like if the banned word is **pirate** then **thepiratebay.com** will be blocked and **wikipedia.org/pirate** won't be blocked.

My questions are;
Will it be enough to block the most popular 10 [trackers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_tracker)?
Will it be enough to block the [udp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) protocol?

Comment: What kind of router is he using? Everthing will depend on that and its functionality.

Comment: Short answer - You'll never be able to block torrent downloads using consumer grade gear if the user has even half a brain.

Comment: @KCotreau, he is using ZyXEL P-660W T1 v3 http://goo.gl/jXhMP

Answer (score 10):

**DO NOT BLOCK UDP!** Doing so would prevent name resolution and likely interfere with any online games and many other applications. Basically you could do nearly nothing with your internet without UDP.

Mircea is right that bandwidth limiting/throttling would work well. This could be done from within his torrent application or from the router if it has a quality firmware (consider tomato and dd-wrt 3rd party firmwares if the stock does not support those QoS features).

Blocking `pirate` in web results would only block those sites. He could still get torrents from other sites.

Blocking the popular trackers would probably work well but peer exchange may circumvent that and blocking like that is a pretty dick move either way.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing the reasoning behind the downvote. I thought it was a decent answer.

Comment: @ErikA what downvote? There are no downvotes on this answer...

Comment: @nhinkle - it was downvoted once before being migrated from SF.

Comment: @ErikA votes are usually transfered with the question when it is migrated, and none appear here. I guess it's possible only the total vote score is moved, not the individual up/down score. At any rate, you get another chance to upvote it here.

Comment: @nihinkle - that's odd. The downvote still appears on the deleted answer over at SF. [link](http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-Wjxz2BP/0/O/i-Wjxz2BP.png).

Comment: This "answer" was indeed downvoted prior to being migrated for the simple reason that you have completely failed to answer the question that was asked. The question is about blocking sites, not limiting bandwidth. I do agree that blocking is not the right approach but that's what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 5):

I would use rate limiting and traffic prioritization. Blocking the traffic will make him to search for alternatives. Limiting his traffic will allow both of you to share the connection in a fair way.

Comment: Agreed.  Many popular routers will allow you to rate-limit certain IPs on your local network, by port even.  On my router (WRT54G) it's under the 'QoS' heading.

Answer (score 1):

Disable UPNP in the Router, then delete any port forwarding that has been configured in the router.

Set a strong password on the Router.